# How to write files to a usb memory? (root)

Tags: android

Tablet usb plug in a memory stick and it would like to access

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

File testFile = new File("mnt/usbhost0");
boolean b1 = testFile.canRead();   //b1 = true
boolean b2 = testFile.canWrite();  //b2 = false
```

Why b2 is false?

My device is rooted

ps. sorry my english bad..

Comment: Your `su` process is a different process, so don't impact your access rights.

Comment: run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su chmod 777 mnt/usbhost0");` and then check??

Comment: I tried.. but not working

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your app's persmissions in the manifest to write to storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i aleady had it